# Class dump z generates empty header

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, gdb, decompiling

When I use class dump z, I don't get any header files, all I get is this:

> /**  * This header is generated by
>   class-dump-z 0.2-0.  * class-dump-z is
>   Copyright (C) 2009 by KennyTM~,
>   licensed under GPLv3.  *  * Source:
>   (null)  */

But if use class dump 3.3.3, I can get the header files. Is there anything I am missing? 
In terminal I typed: class-dump-z path-to-file

Thanks!

**For those wondering why I am not using class dump 3.3.3, it's because it screws up with structs and cfobjectrefs**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class-dump-z was written for iPhone development and will not work with OS X files. Instead, you get a blank file with no error message. See [this page](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/wiki/class_dump_z#Why_you_don%27t_want_to_use_class-dump-z).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but do you by any chance know why the original class dump (3.3.3) messes up with CFStringRef? It makes a struct called CFString, and in it there's a reference to __CFString (CFStingRef) and every time i try to access it i get an EXC BAD ACCESS